# Does completing the mission "closing the rift" in Dragon Age Inquisition end the main quest of the game?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

After siding with the Templars, I now have the choice to immediately start "closing the rift" quest. However, I am very hesitant to start this mission, because I am worried that the game, at least the main quest, will come to an end, and all major character relationships and dialogues will be terminated. I am not specifically asking for a spoiler, but rather some good faith that their is still more main quests to be completed after closing the rift. For example, uniting all factions together?

Does completing the mission "closing the rift" in Dragon Age Inquisition end the main quest of the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Don't hesitate to do that missions any time you like, it mostly opens up the game even more.

I'm not far enough in the game myself to verify this, but I've read that the larger part of the main story is still happening after that mission.

The big change after that mission is :

> You get your own castle, Skyhold instead of Haven as a base

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. By the way what is the correct quest name for "closing the breach?" I thought it was named something different.

Comment: @linuxfreebird: I believe it is called "In Your Heart Shall Burn."  And Mad Scientist is right, there's a lot more game after that quest.

Comment: If anything, everything up to this quest is more of a prologue than anything.